# One of our admin users is replicating multiple times a day CiviCRM 4.6.38 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home, user-account, civicrm.settings.php, user

We are using CiviCRM 4.6.38 Wordpress.

One of our admin users is replicating multiple times a day and I don't know why or how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is deleting the contact/user and recreating an option or are there lots of entries already tied to their id? If it's not an option, do you have any cron scripts or scheduled jobs that might be causing it? https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs

Comment: am pretty sure i have read a couple of earlier Qs about this

Comment: this might give a clue: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27726/100s-of-duplicate-contacts-created-of-current-user-when-using-civicrm