# Contacts Duplicated on Login for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-contacts

We have been facing a recurring issue where Civi is duplicating contacts. We were able to test and confirm that it happens whenever a person logs in, and then another duplicate contact is created every hour from then on by some sort of cron that we have yet to identify.

We are not entirely sure where it's coming from. We have tried turning off plugins we thought could be responsible with no success. We have tried rebuilding the civicrm_uf_match table with no success. We do not believe it is coming from non-Civi related plugins such as Woocommerce or Gravity Forms or Give Donations. We see no evidence that it's role related either.

The only thing we're sure about is that these duplications happen when someone logs in, and that a new duplicate is created every hour after that. The duplicates only contain Name and Email Address.

We are wondering if there is any cron inside of Civi that could be responsible for this, or perhaps it has something to do with our duplication rules?

Wordpress version: 5.4.2
Civi version: 5.26.2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I recall similar tickets. Found a couple. no idea if they help or are similar but here they are. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/197/wordpress-duplicates-my-contacts and https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27726/100s-of-duplicate-contacts-created-of-current-user-when-using-civicrm

Comment: Yes we have tried the solutions listed in both of these tickets with no success, we've rebuilt the civicrm_uf_match table using the solutions listed and still the contacts are duplicated. It's a pickle.

Comment: do your system have wp user with same email address?

Comment: We have double checked the wp_users table and we don't see any duplicate email addresses.